# Controlling puppetserver status after a catalog compilation

Tags: puppet

I would like to be able to restart/stop a puppetserver instance (or at least signal a piece of software) after every compilation of a catalog but I'm failing finding a way to control this. Is it even possible or should I rely in the component receiving the catalog?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly ? restarting puppetserver during puppet agent executing ?

Comment: Restart puppetserver once a catalog has been compiled.

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem.  Why in the world would you want to restart puppetserver after every catalog compilation?  What's the underlying problem that you hope to solve that way?